# CTE MS SQL Query for recuring events

Tags: sql-server-2008, fullcalendar, webforms, common-table-expression

I have been looking for few days now to fix the issue of recurring event on my Fullcalender. I thing most easy way could be to generates Recurring dates based on data on stored in the table.

I have not worked with CTE query in past. What i need is to generate recurring dates  for days example

Every Monday  & Thursday we have a meeting in office for projects.in this case i will put start date = 2012-06-04 
End Date  = 2012-06-31

Now i want to generate SQL query which will show me all the dates starting from 2012-06-04 - till 2012-08-31 for this event & other event based on if they are recurring or not

```
EventID     Date          Title
1          2012-06-04     Project Meeting
1          2012-06-07     Project Meeting
1          2012-06-11     Project Meeting
1          2012-06-14     Project Meeting
1          2012-06-18     Project Meeting
1          2012-06-21     Project Meeting
1          2012-06-25     Project Meeting
1          2012-06-18     Project Meeting
2          2012-05-13     Meeting With Client
3          2012-06-25     Event 3
```

I am able to understand how i can accomplish this I would appreciate help on this or point me to similar example. If i am able to generate this data correctly then i can send these dates along with eventTitle to FullCalender control to display calender of events as show in example below http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

If someone is willing to help he can create table and sample data from sql below. This is MS SQL SERVER 2008 r2 compatible as i have used data type which are supported by MS SQL 2008 only

**Schema With Data**

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EventCalender]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender](
    [EventID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EventTitle] [nvarchar](900) NULL,
    [EventDetails] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [EventStartDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EventEndDate] [date] NULL,
    [EventStartTime] [time](0) NULL,
    [EventEndTime] [time](0) NULL,
    [EventRecurring] [bit] NULL,
    [EventEnumDays] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EventBlockDate] [bit] NULL,
    [EventVisibleOnWebsite] [bit] NULL,
    [EventActive] [bit] NULL,
    [EventType] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [LanguageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EventCreatedOn] [date] NULL,
    [EventShowTime] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EventCalender] ON
INSERT [dbo].[EventCalender] ([EventID], [EventTitle], [EventDetails], [EventStartDate], [EventEndDate], [EventStartTime], [EventEndTime], [EventRecurring], [EventEnumDays], [EventBlockDate], [EventVisibleOnWebsite], [EventActive], [EventType], [LanguageID], [EventCreatedOn], [EventShowTime]) VALUES (1, N'Project Meeting', N'Every Monday, Thrusday', CAST(0xC1350B00 AS Date), CAST(0x19360B00 AS Date), CAST(0x00A08C0000000000 AS Time), CAST(0x00B8A10000000000 AS Time), 1, N'2,5,7', 0, 0, 1, N'EVENT', 1, CAST(0xB6350B00 AS Date), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[EventCalender] ([EventID], [EventTitle], [EventDetails], [EventStartDate], [EventEndDate], [EventStartTime], [EventEndTime], [EventRecurring], [EventEnumDays], [EventBlockDate], [EventVisibleOnWebsite], [EventActive], [EventType], [LanguageID], [EventCreatedOn], [EventShowTime]) VALUES (2, N'Meeting With Client', N'Event Details 2', CAST(0xBA350B00 AS Date), CAST(0xBA350B00 AS Date), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 1, N'EVENT', 1, CAST(0xB6350B00 AS Date), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[EventCalender] ([EventID], [EventTitle], [EventDetails], [EventStartDate], [EventEndDate], [EventStartTime], [EventEndTime], [EventRecurring], [EventEnumDays], [EventBlockDate], [EventVisibleOnWebsite], [EventActive], [EventType], [LanguageID], [EventCreatedOn], [EventShowTime]) VALUES (3, N'Event 3', N'Event Details 3', CAST(0xAB350B00 AS Date), CAST(0xAB350B00 AS Date), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 0, N'EVENT', 1, CAST(0xB6350B00 AS Date), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[EventCalender] ([EventID], [EventTitle], [EventDetails], [EventStartDate], [EventEndDate], [EventStartTime], [EventEndTime], [EventRecurring], [EventEnumDays], [EventBlockDate], [EventVisibleOnWebsite], [EventActive], [EventType], [LanguageID], [EventCreatedOn], [EventShowTime]) VALUES (5, N'Weekly Meeting', N'Weekly Event', CAST(0xA3350B00 AS Date), CAST(0x01380B00 AS Date), CAST(0x00D0B60000000000 AS Time), NULL, 1, N'2,', 0, 1, 1, N'ACTIVITY', 2, NULL, 0)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EventCalender] OFF
/****** Object:  Default [DF_EventCalender_EventEndDate]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventCalender_EventEndDate]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [EventEndDate]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_EventCalender_EventStartTime]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventCalender_EventStartTime]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [EventStartTime]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_EventCalender_EventEndTime]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventCalender_EventEndTime]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [EventEndTime]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_EventCalender_EventRecurring]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventCalender_EventRecurring]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EventRecurring]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_EventCalender_EventEnumDays]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventCalender_EventEnumDays]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [EventEnumDays]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_EventCalender_EventBlockDate]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventCalender_EventBlockDate]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EventBlockDate]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_EventCalender_EventVisibleOnWebsite]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventCalender_EventVisibleOnWebsite]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EventVisibleOnWebsite]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_EventCalender_EventActive]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventCalender_EventActive]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EventActive]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_EventCalender_EventShowTime]    Script Date: 05/24/2012 20:18:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventCalender] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventCalender_EventShowTime]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EventShowTime]
GO
```

Comment: Do you need to use a CTE?  You can also do this type of date generation using a [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

Comment: I think it can be easily implement using CTE But i am not sure. I have never worked with Tally Table will take me some time to understand how it works .. Thanks & appreciate you reply

Comment: It would be helpful to put your import data into a usable insert command like you've nicely done with your DDL.

Comment: Tim: I have done as insert also you can find all the scheme & insert statement added to the bottom of the question. I would appreciate if you help

Comment: Tim: If it works then it is great otherwise one way can be to import this to a flat file & importing into the database from flat file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may give you a starting point on how to create recurring dates with a CTE:

```
;with Dates as (
    select cast('2012-06-04' as date) as StartDate, cast('2012-08-31' as date) as EndDate
),
RecursiveCTE as (
    select StartDate, EndDate, StartDate as EventDate
    from Dates
    union all
    select StartDate, EndDate, dateadd(dd, 7, EventDate)
    from RecursiveCTE
    where dateadd(dd, 7, EventDate) < Enddate
)
select * from RecursiveCTE
```

**UPDATE**

Using your schema and insert, here is a recursive CTE that gives the desired result:

```
;with Calendar as (
    select EventID, EventTitle, EventStartDate, EventEndDate, EventEnumDays, EventRecurring, EventStartDate as PlannedDate
    from EventCalender
    where EventActive = 1
    union all
    select EventID, EventTitle, EventStartDate, EventEndDate, EventEnumDays, EventRecurring, dateadd(dd, 1, PlannedDate)
    from Calendar
    where EventRecurring = 1
        and dateadd(dd, 1, PlannedDate) <= EventEndDate
)
select EventID, PlannedDate as [Date], EventTitle
from Calendar
where ',' + EventEnumDays + ',' like '%,' + cast(datepart(dw, PlannedDate) as char(1)) + ',%'
    or EventEnumDays is null
order by EventID, PlannedDate
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Note that you will have to make some modifications (possibly a case/switch) if you want to include monthly or yearly events, as I'm relying upon "day of the week" (dw) here for the weekly stuff.

Also, a recursive CTE can be [one of the slowest methods of counting](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/), which is essentially what we're doing here.  A [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) may be a better option if speed is paramount.

Comment: I modified your query it gets me data only for Monday for eventID=1 but not Thursday.  ;with Dates as (
    select cast('2012-06-04' as date) as StartDate, cast('2012-06-31' as date) as EndDate
),
RecursiveCTE as (
    select EventID,EventTitle, EventStartDate, EventEndDate, EventStartDate as EventDate
    from EventCalender
    union all
    select EventID, EventTitle,EventStartDate, EventEndDate, dateadd(dd, 7, EventDate)
    from RecursiveCTE
    where dateadd(dd, 7, EventDate) < EventEndDate
)
select * from RecursiveCTE order by EventID

Comment: `;with Dates as (
    select cast('2012-06-04' as date) as EventStartDate, cast('2012-06-31' as date) as EventEndDate
),
RecursiveCTE as (
    select EventID,EventTitle, EventStartDate, EventEndDate, EventStartDate as EventDate
    from EventCalender
    union all
    select EventID, EventTitle,EventStartDate, EventEndDate, dateadd(dd, 7, EventDate)
    from RecursiveCTE
    where dateadd(dd, 7, EventDate) < EventEndDate
)
select * from RecursiveCTE order by EventID`

Comment: I made change data by putting end date also for each event. Your query work but it doesn't give desired result. I am not sure how to modify it to take enum of days [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] from table column and accordingly pass it to the query so that it will give me exact dates days for recurring events ..

Comment: Thanks Tim, It is extremely close to my data but It gives correct data for Monday in EventID=1 but for Thrusday It is returning 11,18,24 which actually is Friday while it should return me 10,17,24,31. I am so close. I looked into the CTE but i am not able to understand where to make change to get the exact result. I would appreciate this favor from you.

Comment: Very Strange When i when i change EventEnumDays to 2,5,7 it gets me correct dates for Monday(2) & Saturday(7) But for Thursday(5) it returns Friday... I am not sure why it is behaving like this..

Comment: Further Bug: Even if i keep only one day in EventEnumDays i.e 2 for eventID 1, it will still show be result as `EventID     Date       EventTitle
----------- ---------- 
1           2012-06-04 Project Meeting
1           2012-06-11 Project Meeting
1           2012-06-18 Project Meeting
1           2012-06-25 Project Meeting
1           2012-07-02 Project Meeting
1           2012-07-09 Project Meeting
1           2012-07-16 Project Meeting
1           2012-07-23 Project Meeting
1           2012-07-30 Project Meeting`

Comment: If you add `datename(dw, PlannedDate)` to the final select, what does it return?

Comment: I am totally new to CTE & to be honest i am bit lost in it No down who have give a solution which is working unfortunately with unexpected results. I am so close to a perfect solution... I hope i acn crack it with your help

Comment: Based upon my limited understanding of what you're trying to achieve, I am unable to come up with unexpected results.  Your "Further Bug" post seems like it is the expected result.  One word of caution: only put digits and commas in the EventEnumDays column.  Spaces and such would be bad.

Comment: I appreciate you help & answers. Even i am confused by the result. Your Answers is very close i will wait for some more time otherwise i will mark your answer as more I have already given your answer up-vote. I should have avoided term Bug since i dont have much knowledge of CTE query Subject

Comment: I worked on your advice & deleted the entry in the EventEnumDays Field & now it is works I used to encounter these kind of error in sql 7 version in early 1999. Appreciate Your help .. Great Query..

Comment: Tim: I appreciate you answer.. So far you have done it in a very nice way. You being a guru on this subject i agree that recursion of any type can be slow specially in CTE query. It would be great if you can also give me a version of Tally Table of same query as it would be a great start for me. To be honest i had never hear of it before it seems totally a new concept to be. I would appreciate your reply. Thanks